# Filling data with with information from 1 of 3 cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I hope I can explain sufficiently for someone to understand and be able to help, I have 27000 records to update into one column.

I'm hoping to use a formula to fill column D with data from column A but if that cell is blank use data from column B and again if that column is blank use data column c.

]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTwI7.png

Comment: Need to see a visual example. But it looks like you’re gonna need an ```IFS``` statement

Comment: Would a VBA answer be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(A1<>"",A1, IF(B1<>"",B1,IF(C1="","",C1)))
```

Comment: that worked like a dream, thank you all for the help you amazing people

Answer (score 1):

May be like this in your cell D2

```
=IF(A2<>"", A2, IF(A2="", B2, Value(C2)))
```

Comment: Hi, that worked for the first two columns but returns a 0 if the only data if supplied in the 3rd Column.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be because I have a formula in the 3rd column.

Comment: If your C2 is a result of a formula I edit the formula may be that works

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use `IF`, and so is more flexible for use with longer ranges.

```
=INDEX(FILTER(A1:C1,A1:C1>"",""),1)
```

It `FILTER`s the row for non-empty text cells, and returns the first one via `INDEX`.